# retrieve multiple columns from one row

Tags: mysql

i have a table  (actual column names)

```
id | name | image1  | image2  | image3  | image4  | image5  | image6  | image7 etc
2    joe    1.jpg     2.jpg     3.jpg   etc
```

all i simply  need to do is  select just the entries in image(x) columns & name (there are other column names buti  dont want them) so i can display

For example:

```
select name, image(x) from table where id=2
```

this should produce an array so i can run through the loop and end up with

```
name
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

etc wich i could then echo out? - this must a pretty standard(ish) type query ?

i assuming that i have to assign image with image[0] or something in the loop ?

Comment: Did you try writing this code?

Comment: It appears that you want to pivot your columns and make them rows.  Read the answers at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605604/mysql-pivot-query-results-with-group-by

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way I would structure this table. You should just use `id | name | image` and have multiple records for each name. Then you can just do a

```
SELECT image FROM table WHERE name = 'joe'
```

This way you can pull back and build an array like the one you want easily without the kludgy (x) stuff.

Comment: if so, I would rather use 3 or 2 tables: user(id,name), imageUser(user_id,image) and if there is image info - image table.

Comment: This depends on the level of complexity of the system. Normalization is good, but if this is the only table that will ever exist in the database there is no need for it IMO.

Comment: i dont have a choice in structure of the table i'm afraid - thats what ive been given to work with