# MySQL dynamic-pivot

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have a table of product parts like this:

**Parts**

```
part_id      part_type      product_id
--------------------------------------
1            A              1
2            B              1
3            A              2
4            B              2
5            A              3
6            B              3
```

and I want a query that will return a table like this:

```
product_id      part_A_id      part_B_id
----------------------------------------
1               1              2
2               3              4
3               5              6
```

In its actual implementation there will be millions of product parts

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: What you're looking for is usually referred to as a dynamic pivot.

Comment: How many part types are there?

Comment: @ruakh nothing pretty or useful, I've forgotten so much mysql

Comment: @Lamak There will be about 20 product parts

Comment: @JoeStefanelli Will google dynamic pivots now

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL or other?

Comment: Re: "nothing pretty or useful": Part of the point of showing what you've tried is simply to show that you've tried *something*. (A lot of question-askers don't, and it can be hard to summon the motivation to help those folks!) Another part is to help clarify the question; if you post a query that you've already written, and explain why it doesn't do what you need -- even if it doesn't come close -- then that can help clarify what it is that you do need.

Comment: @ruakh I hear what you are saying. In this case I thought my attempt would do little but muddy the waters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function but you can model it using an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement.  For a dynamic version, you will need to use prepared statements:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when part_type = ''',
      part_type,
      ''' then part_id end) AS part_',
      part_type, '_id'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  parts;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT product_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM parts 
                   GROUP BY product_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9d59/2)

If you had only a few columns, then you can use a Static version:

```
select product_id,
  max(case when part_type ='A' then part_id end) as Part_A_Id,
  max(case when part_type ='B' then part_id end) as Part_B_Id
from parts
group by product_id
```

Comment: Why is max here ? Is it because it needs to be aggreate function there and it also could be sum or something else ?

Comment: @Harlsten There has to be an aggregate function for this. `sum` wouldn't make sense because it's a `part_id`, for this particular example you'd need to use `max` or `min`.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a PIVOT keyword, but with MySQL you will need to use either a lot of CASE/IF statements or a lot of JOINs.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605604/mysql-pivot-query-results-with-group-by) is a previous post of how to do this.

Answer (score -3):

just reference it twice - (you don't really have much of a question here)

```
select a.product_id, a.part_id "part_a_id", b.part_id "part_b_id"
from parts a, parts b
where a.product_id = b.product_id
```

Comment: I think you misread the question.  You should go back and re-examine his example.

Comment: i think this produces the results requested.  the question is poor imo.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken this produces additional results that are not in his results.  For example: it would produce a row with (1,1,1) as well as (1,1,2) as well as (1,2,1) as well as (1,2,2).