# mySQL reformat query results into pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

May I ask for a little help with the following please ?

My query results are returned like ...

```
cDate       posId    val
14/01/2011  0        200
14/01/2011  1        199
…       
14/01/2011  8        198
14/01/2011  9        197
06/03/2015  0        264
06/03/2015  1        264
…       
06/03/2015  8        261
06/03/2015  9        264
```

Is it possible to 'reformat' the output like this ...

```
Position    14/01/2011   06/03/2015
0           200          264
1           199          264
2           195          264
3           192          264
4           190          264
5           195          263
6           197          261
7           199          260
8           198          261
9           197          264
```

I'd like to read through these rows in php and put together a csv file that I can download.

I think this [Crosstabs](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78) section at artfulsoftware.com may contain the answer for me, but I'm just not 'getting it' right now.

May I ask you for a pointer or two please ? Am I heading in the right direction with Pivot Tables ?

Thank you.

Comment: And the dates may be of any numbers ? Right now in your example there are only 2.

Comment: Google "mysql pivot" if you know that there are two columns.  Otherwise, google "mysql dynamic pivot".

Comment: @OP: Solution for your query is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12630301/767881

Comment: @ Abhik Chakraborty. I was trying to keep thing simple for myself. So I was just using 2 dates presently.

Comment: Gordon Linoff. Thanks for the pointers, I will google "mysql dynamic pivot".

Comment: @Ravinder. Thanks, will check out the SO question.