# MySQL - Join on variable/dynamic number of rows from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables.

```
+---------+
|  items  |
+---------+
| item_id |
| ...     |
+---------+

+----------------------+
|   item_text_values   |
+----------------------+
| item_text_value_id   |
| item_id              |
| custom_field_name_id |
| value                |
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
|  custom_field_names  |
+----------------------+
| custom_field_name_id |
| index                |
| name                 |
+----------------------+
```

the count of item_text_values is unknown. It can be three 3 or 10 or more. I would like to have a view or stored procedure that returns me row with variable columns depending on how many item_text_values records are there.

I have classic join

```
SELECT *
 FROM items
LEFT JOIN item_text_values ON item_text_values.item_id = items.item_id
LEFT JOIN custom_field_names ON custom_field_names.custom_field_name_id = item_text_values.custom_field_name_id
WHERE items.item_id = 1
```

which returns me 2 rows if there are 2 records of item_text_values. 
And I want to merge these two rows into one with variable columns depending on how many item_text_values are there. Don't know if this is even possible.

Thank you

Comment: Have you learned how to use GROUP BY?

Comment: @The TTG Guy group by only give me one row with the static number of columns.

Comment: Google:  "MySQL dynamic pivot".

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630128/mysql-dynamic-pivot Looks good, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL dynamic-pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630128/mysql-dynamic-pivot)