# UNION with multiple tables in MYSQL issue

Tags: mysql, union

I tried it but no luck,I have two tables "crm_rentals" and "crm_sales".

Both have same structure.

```
Id | portals_name
1  | {dubizzle}{JustRentals}{JustProperty}{propertyfinder}{bayut}
2  | {dubizzle}{JustRentals}{JustProperty}{propertyfinder}{bayut}
3  | {JustRentals}{JustProperty}{propertyfinder}
4  | {dubizzle}{JustProperty}{bayut}
```

I want to get NUMBER of each portal in both tables,here is what i tried

```
select sum(dubizzle) dubizzle,sum(JustRentals) JustRentals,
sum(JustProperty) JustProperty,sum(propertyfinder) propertyfinder 
from ( (select count(id) as dubizzle from crm_rentals where 
portals_name like '%dubizzle%'
UNION
select count(id) as dubizzle from crm_sales where portals_name 
like  '%dubizzle%'
) a ,
(select count(id) as JustRentals from crm_rentals where 
 portals_name like '%JustRentals%'
UNION
select count(id) as JustRentals from crm_sales where 
portals_name like  '%JustRentals%') b,
(select count(id)  as JustProperty from crm_rentals where 
portals_name like '%JustProperty%'
UNION
select count(id)  as JustProperty from crm_sales where portals_name 
like '%JustProperty%') c ,
(select count(id) as propertyfinder from crm_rentals where 
portals_name like '%propertyfinder%'
UNION
select count(id) as propertyfinder from crm_rentals where 
portals_name like '%propertyfinder%'
) d )
```

I want to get result like

```
Dubizzle    JustRentals  JustProperty Propertyfinder Others
100           100         100          100            100
```

**Question**: I can not get this result,my query give me Syntax error.

**UPDATE** I tried this but syntax error

```
select * from (select @table1:=(select count(id) as dubizzle 
from  crm_rentals where portals_name like '%dubizzle%') a,
@table2:=(select count(id) as dubizzle from crm_sales 
where portals_name   like '%dubizzle%') b, (@table1 +@table2) 
as dubizzle) f,
((select @table1:=(select count(id) as JustRentals from 
crm_rentals where portals_name like '%JustRentals%') c,
@table2:=(select count(id) as JustRentals from crm_sales 
where portals_name like '%JustRentals%') d, (@table1 +@table2)
 as JustRentals)  ff) AS f
```

Comment: You forgot to ask question... Where did you stuck?

Comment: My question is, I can not get this result,my query give me issue.

Comment: I have not got time now to write a complete answer, but it might be worth your while to look at this post for ideas: [dynamic pivot table with MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630128/mysql-dynamic-pivot). In your case the pivot query mabe does not need to be dynamic, so just use the generated select query shown in the post directly. You should also be able to get away with just doing one `UNION ALL` with your tables and then work from there.

Comment: My car give me an issue. Can you tell me wahts wrong? Is it so hard to tell what issue you have? Do you think we are mindreaders?

Comment: Do you have any result of you query?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: there is syntax error

Comment: Try posting the exact error message, it might help.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') a ,

Answer (score 1):

you can try by this way

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
(select count(id) as dubizzle from crm_rentals where portals_name like '%dubizzle%') AS a,
(select count(id) as JustRentals from crm_rentals where portals_name like '%JustRentals%') b,
(select count(id)  as JustProperty from crm_rentals where portals_name like '%JustProperty%') AS c
UNION
(select count(id) as dubizzle from crm_sales where portals_name like '%dubizzle%') AS a,
(select count(id) as JustRentals from crm_sales where portals_name like  '%JustRentals%') AS b,
(select count(id)  as JustProperty from crm_sales where portals_name like '%JustProperty%') AS c
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select
    sum(a.dubizzle) as dubizzle,
    sum(b.JustRentals) as JustRentals,
    sum(c.JustProperty) as JustProperty,
    sum(d.propertyfinder) as propertyfinder 
from
(
    (
    select count(id) as dubizzle
    from crm_rentals
    where portals_name like '%dubizzle%'
    UNION
    select count(id) as dubizzle
    from crm_sales
    where portals_name like '%dubizzle%'
    ) as a ,

    (
    select count(id) as JustRentals
    from crm_rentals
    where portals_name like '%JustRentals%'
    UNION
    select count(id) as JustRentals
    from crm_sales
    where portals_name like  '%JustRentals%'
    ) as b,

    (
    select count(id)  as JustProperty
    from crm_rentals
    where portals_name like '%JustProperty%'
    UNION
    select count(id)  as JustProperty
    from crm_sales
    where portals_name like '%JustProperty%'
    ) as c ,

    (
    select count(id) as propertyfinder
    from crm_rentals
    where portals_name like '%propertyfinder%'
    UNION
    select count(id) as propertyfinder
    from crm_rentals
    where portals_name like '%propertyfinder%'
    ) as d
)
```

Please try this and return here query result.

BTW try to keep your code clear :)

Comment: @MuhammadAli In which row?

Comment: server version for the right syntax to use near ') a , at line 16

Comment: Try edit sub queries like this:
 (
    select count(id) as dubizzle
    from crm_rentals
    where portals_name like '%dubizzle%'
    UNION
    select count(id) as dubizzle
    from crm_sales
    where portals_name like '%dubizzle%'
    ) as a ,
)
I mean add "as" statement to alias