# MySQL select all tags that are share common relationship with another entity

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following table structure:

```
tags            image_tags          image
------------    ----------------    ---------------
id  tag         tag_id  image_id    id    etc...
------------    ----------------    ---------------
1   apple       1       1           1   image_1.jpg
2   banana      2       1           2   image_2.jpg
3   cherry      2       2
                3       2
```

Tags are joined to images through a many-to-many relationship.

I want to get a list of tags that appear together in at least one image.  Something like:

```
-----------------
a        b
-----------------
apple    banana
banana   cherry

etc..
```

Each tag pair should only appear once, and the order of the pair doesn't matter.  We'll be using this data to create a .dot file for a network graph.

I'm not sure exactly how to structure a query like this.

Comment: group_concat() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html  Though given your sample data I don't see `Apple,Cherry` exists in your output

Comment: @xQbert - You're right about 'apple,cherry'!  Thanks, I edited the question to clarify.  The issue isn't the group_concat(), but getting the relationships to begin with.-

Comment: ah so could there be more n (unlimited) tags per image? and do you want separate colums for each?  (If so this is beginning to sound like a dynamic pivot table  like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630128/mysql-dynamic-pivot  Or do you always want to show 2 columns... so if there were 3 tags associated to an image you would see A-->B  A-->C  B-->C?

Comment: @xQbert -Yes!  I do always want to show just two columns.  Your last sentence is correct.  A->B, A->C, B->C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're after just 2 columns each time then a self join and 2 joins to Tags is needed.  This will eliminate all records with Only 1 tag for an image however.  If you need those we need to alter some of the joins.

This will account for n records per image and only 1 pairing of each.  EG. Apple, Cherry and not Cherry Apple.  It's accomplished by matching `IT.Tag_ID < IT2.Tag_ID`

```
SELECT Distinct T.tag A, T2.Tag B
FROM image_tags IT
INNER JOIN tags T
 on T.ID = IT.Tag_Id
INNER JOIN Image_tags IT2
 on IT2.image_ID = IT.Image_ID
and IT.Tag_ID < IT2.Tag_ID
INNER JOIN Tags T2
  on IT2.tag_ID = T2.Tag_ID
```

With your data this would give you.

```
-----------------
a        b
-----------------
apple    banana
banana   cherry
```

However if you added a tag to image 1 of Tag 3 then you would get

```
-----------------
a        b
-----------------
apple    banana
banana   cherry
apple    cherry
```

This is because 3 combinations of 2 is 3.  Banana Cherry would be listed twice due to image 2 but the distinct eliminates the duplicate.  The < makes it a combination where as if we didn't use anything we'd end up with a permutation. (Apple Banana) would be considered different than (Banana Apple)  Based on your output I believe you're after the combination.

----------------------------------OLD RESPONSE_--------------

I no longer believe you're looking for the aggregate function group_concat() found in mySQL

This allows you to combine multiple rows into one.

```
Select group_Concat(T.tag ORDER BY t.tag SEPARATOR ',') as All_Image_Tags
FROM image_tags IT
INNER JOIN tags T
 on T.ID = IT.Tag_Id
GROUP BY IT.image_ID
```

Maybe your just after the pairings though..

```
Select concat(A.Tags, ',', B.tags)
FROM tags a
cross join tags B
Where A.Tag < B.Tag
```

Comment: Query #1 is close, and I was able to create such a query before, but is there an easy way to list each tag one per row instead of a concatenated list per line?

Comment: Updated resposne assuming you mean 1 per column.  Also unsure if you have N possible tags per image.  So this accounts for that as well.  assuming you only want 1 occurance of each.

Comment: That's it!  Wow, thanks for the help!  The part that was tripping me up was the AND in the JOIN clause.  Clearly, I need to enhance my SQL fu

Comment: Using and/or in joins becomes quite necessary when you have compound criteria.  It is especially important in outer joins (like a left) when you want to filter data from the "RIGHT" table  if you do it in a where you negate the outer join, making it an inner, but if you do it on the join itself, it applies the limit before the join thus retaining the outer join!