# Select mysql data in un-normalised form

Tags: mysql, normalization

Apologies if this seems a 'stupid' question - I don't really know the right term to describe what I am trying to do (and thus searching for help on it was bit fruitless).

Basically, I initially had data that was in the form:

```
|      timestamp      | category A | category B | .......| category n|
| 2011-12-02 00:05:00 |    23.63   |    27.00   | .......|   24.03   |
| 2011-12-02 00:10:00 |    23.75   |    24.42   | .......|   24.45   |
| 2011-12-02 00:15:00 |    23.31   |    23.96   | .......|   26.54   |
```

I put this data into a database (and normalised it) so that it exists in the database as follows:

```
+---------------------+--------------+-------+
| timestamp           | catergory_id | value |
+---------------------+--------------+-------+
| 2011-12-02 00:05:00 |            2 | 27.00 |
| 2011-12-02 00:10:00 |            2 | 24.42 |
| 2011-12-02 00:15:00 |            2 | 23.96 |
| 2011-12-02 00:20:00 |            2 | 23.73 |
| 2011-12-02 00:25:00 |            2 | 23.73 |
+---------------------+--------------+-------+
```

What I am trying to select different categories by timestamp (to enable comparison) , like so:

```
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| timestamp           | cat_a | cat_b |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| 2011-12-02 00:05:00 | 23.63 | 27.00 |
| 2011-12-02 00:10:00 | 23.75 | 24.42 |
| 2011-12-02 00:15:00 | 23.31 | 23.96 |
| 2011-12-02 00:20:00 | 23.00 | 23.73 |
| 2011-12-02 00:25:00 | 22.91 | 23.73 |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
```

This is basically similar to the original data structure (But I would like to select/compare between multiple and variable, categories not just two).

I have been able to to this using `join` (after selecting the individual categories in individual tables). This is okay for say comparing across two categories, but seems quite inefficient, particularly if I want to select say 15 or 20 different categories to compare. It is also problematic if a particular category is missing a data point.

(The other way I have been doing this is by selecting individual tables and later "merging" the data in the python application in which it is later used, but this also seems equally inefficient)

I feel like there must be an easier or more intuitive way to do this in mysql- and I am just missing something quite basic. I don't really want to de-normalize (As there is a lot of categories, and it makes sense to have it normalized for other uses, besides this one).

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a pivot table problem. MySQL doesn't have a built-in SQL extension to make pivot tables like some other DBMSs do so they are a bit tricky. You can find one way of making them here: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Comment: Right - "pivot table" - that seems to be the term I was missing! Quick search suggests there is quite a bit of material out there on this. Thanks! (and thanks for the link too)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem used the python data tool [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). (This won't suit those interested in a pure MySQL solution - for this case, check out Joni's solutions above, or have a look at some of the similar stackoverflow answers e.g. [mysql pivot query results with GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605604/mysql-pivot-query-results-with-group-by) or [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)).

Firstly I created a pandas dataframe with the data I wanted to select/compare (using the `sql.read_frame` method from `pandas.io`, and the appropriate `sql_query`):

```
df=sql.read_frame(sql_query,DB_connection)
```

This created a dataframe as such:

`df.head():`

```
             timestamp       category_id  value
0  2011-01-01 00:00:00                 4   22.05
1  2011-01-01 00:05:00                 4   24.10
2  2011-01-01 00:10:00                 4   23.98
3  2011-01-01 00:15:00                 4   24.10
4  2011-01-01 00:20:00                 4   24.10
```

This was then "pivoted" using the `pandas.pivot_table` method:

```
df2=df.pivot_table(rows='timestamp',cols='category_id',values='value')
```

Which create the exact output I was after:

`df2.head():`

```
category_id              2      4      5      6      7
timestamp                                             
2011-01-01 00:00:00  23.43  22.05  25.07  19.47  21.32
2011-01-01 00:05:00  25.31  24.10  25.69  21.32  22.94
2011-01-01 00:10:00  25.31  23.98  24.84  21.32  22.59
2011-01-01 00:15:00  25.31  24.10  25.47  21.10  21.39
2011-01-01 00:20:00  25.31  24.10  25.69  20.01  17.9
```

Hope someone else finds this useful!